# pop up window not closing after the parent window is reload

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my parent jsp page I've used:

```
function popUpClosed() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

And in child (popup window) I've used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onunload = function() {
                if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.popUpClosed();
                }
        };
</script>
```

by this code, parent window is reloading after inserting data from popup window but popup window is not closing, I've to manually close the popup window. **How can the popup window be made self close??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the window in your popup change the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onunload = function() {
                if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.popUpClosed();
                }
                window.close();
        };
</script>
```

Refer here: [How to close the current window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close).
`onunload` is called whenever your page unloads. 
If you are posting data, by a submit button, you are unloading the document.

This is not the same as closing the windows.
If you want to capture only the close of the window, you should use something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = windowExit;
function windowExit(){
    //do somethng
    //check that you are not submitting.
}
```

Comment: After reloading the parent window I've to close the popup window. Iam new to JS. Please can U tell me, where to put your code and where to make change in my code. THANK YOU...

Comment: I modified my answer, take a look. This should close the popup.

Comment: onunload and onbeforeunload capture the same window event thing, onbeforeunload just executes before onunload.

Comment: That is why I have a check that you are not submitting. I guess the english is a little misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two sample functions that open and close a popup window. If you create your window within a variable, you can then target the window you've opened, meaning you can close it.

```
<script>
function openWin()
{
    myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin()
{
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```